# Flutter - TextField no se puede modificar

Tags: flutter, dart

Necesito dejar en un texfield (hinttext) el valor de un campo obtenido desde un backend (snapshot.data), luego de esto una vez que haga un tap en el TextField se pueda mantener el mismo texto pero que se pueda modificar...

Código de mi Widget TextField

```
TextField(

                                  minLines: 10,
                                  maxLines: 10,
                                  controller: detalleController,
                                  autocorrect: false,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: snapshot.data.descripcion,
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: Color(0xFFFFF3E0),
                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    ),
                                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

El `hint` solo es un texto de guía, no es algo que se pueda modificar, para eso necesitas asignarle un `controller` con el valor que deseas.

```dart
//esto debe estar fuera del método build

 final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController(text:"my_value");


TextField(
                                  minLines: 10,
                                  maxLines: 10,
                                  controller: controller,
                                  autocorrect: false,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: snapshot.data.descripcion,
                                    filled: true,
                                    fillColor: Color(0xFFFFF3E0),
                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    ),
                                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

Para modificar el contenido sin borrar lo anterior simplemente concatenas:

```dart
void actualizarValor() {
 controller.text = controller.text + "valor nuevo";
}
```

Y si quieres poner el cursor en la parte final para que continue editando, puedes hacer esto

```dart
void actualizarValor() {
 controller.text = controller.text + "valor nuevo";
controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length));
}
```

Comment: Gracias como siempre diegoveloper. Efectivamente uso un controller, sin embargo, no veo la forma de modificar el contenido del TextFormField, necesito modificar el texto sin que me elimine el original y lo que quede en el controller, lo llevo llevo como parámetro a la base de datos como valor actualizado.

Comment: revisa mi respuesta actualizada